# Matching values between cells on two sheets within a threshold

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking to find some assistance creating a formula that can compare the value of cells on two sheets.

For instance

Sheet1:a1 (1234.12)
Sheet2:a1 (1234.14)

Is there a formula that can return a match(true) between the two cells within a threshold of +/- .05?

Thanks,

Comment: so you want True if Sheet1:a1 = Sheet2:a1 +/- .05?

Answer (score 0):

Use ABS to return the absolute difference and test.

```
=ABS(Sheet1!A1-Sheet2!A1)<=.05
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the IF() function in Excel as shown below.

`=IF(ABS(Sheet1!A1-Sheet2!A1)<=0.05, TRUE(), FALSE())`